# Jquery first() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem:** I can not select first child of `<li>` tag by `first()`. I got an undefined alert. Sorry I'm a beginner.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<li data-filtertext="" class="contentUpdate"><a href="#1-1" >Part 1</a></li>
<li data-filtertext="" class="contentUpdate"><a href="#1-2" >Part 2</a></li>
```

**Here is my Jquery:**

```
$(".contentUpdate").click(function() {
  alert($(this).first().attr('href'));
  $("#mainContent").html("new HTML");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".contentUpdate").click(function() {
    alert($(this).children().first().attr('href'));
    $("#mainContent").html("new HTML");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another:

```
$(".contentUpdate").click(function() {
  alert($(this).children(a:first).attr('href'));
  $("#mainContent").html("new HTML");
});
```